# Creation of table in mySQL

Tags: mysql

when I am going to fire query for creating table in mySQL 5.0 I got following exception    java.sql.sqlexception incorrect information in file frm  Please give me solution for this?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_vpedutech (srno INT(10) NOT NULL,
                                          TheGroup     VARCHAR(50) NULL,      
                                          make        VARCHAR(50) NULL,       
                                          model       VARCHAR(50) NULL,       
                                          description     VARCHAR(255)    NULL,       
                                          quantity        VARCHAR(50) NULL,       
                                          modelNotKnown       boolean NULL  );


java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect information in file: './erp_vpedutech/tmp_vpedutech.frm'
```

Comment: The statement is far from readable (you can use multiple lines!). Furthermore, reading this error, I doubt whether this error is a MySQL syntax error at all.

Comment: There is no issue for creating table may be another issue.

Comment: See [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,106192,269945#msg-269945) maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine in mysql 5.1

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine in [<kbd>**SQL Fiddle**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4104b) check that